# looks not easy, seems not easy

Tags: negation

Are these sentences correct?

1. It looks not easy.
2. It seems not easy.

Or do I need to say like these?

1. It doesn't look easy.
2. It doesn't seem easy.

Answer (score -1):

> It looks not easy. 
>   It seems not easy.

... are grammatically correct but would sound rather odd. It is not recommended.

> It doesn't look easy. 
>   It doesn't seem easy.

... are grammatically correct and sound fine. This is how normal speech is and you should go with this.